# Are "-D" (define) macros ever relevant to the compiler on already-preprocessed C/C++?

Tags: build, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor

Do any C/C++ **compilers** (not preprocessors) ever consider-as-significant macros defined at the command-line?  This question includes both user-defined macros and well-known (compiler-or-system-specific) macros.

(I'm not asking about compiler-switches, but rather, only that SINGLE switch-to-define-macros at the command line.)

For example, if you've already "pre-processed" the `myfile.cpp` to a `myfile.i`, and then want to compile that `myfile.i` to a `myfile.obj/myfile.o`, does it EVER make sense to have `-Dmacro` to define some "macro" at the command-line for the `myfile.i`==>`myfile.obj/myfile.o`?

Similarly, does the **linker** EVER consider-as-significant macros (defined anywhere)?

Comment: No answer on this question is correct, because I can invalidate it by writing a compiler that contradicts the answer. Please refine your scope.

Comment: @nightcracker: Let's be generous and assume that the question is asking about existing implementations, rather than theoretical future implementations.

Comment: Should we assume that the OP is talking about what it says in ISO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Some debugging formats will record the preprocessor definitions so they can be accessed from within the debugger.

(But I know of no linker which accepts preprocessor flags.)